# Apple says you cannot mix page-based and hierarchal navigation in a Watch app. But the Activity app does. How?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

Apple's [developer guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/InterfaceStyles.html) says that you cannot mix page-based and hierarchical navigation in a Watch App:

> Although you cannot mix page-based and hierarchical navigation styles in your app, you can supplement these base navigation styles with modal presentations.

This appears to be true, as calling `pushControllerWithName:context:` from a view with page segues does nothing.

However, in Apple's Activity App, you can swipe between the Activity and Sharing pages, but when you click on a person's name in the Sharing page, it uses a hierarchal-style (not modal) transition to that person's activity.

How is this being done? Is there a custom view type being used?

Answer (score 0):

You can mix hierarchical and page-based Interface Controllers easily in WatchKit. The only restriction is that you can't mix different navigation types in your root controller. But as soon as you are navigating to a different Interface Controller, you can do it modally or in a hierarchical way.

You can present page based InterfaceControllers modally using `self.presentController(withNames:,contexts:)`. You can also present a single view controller using hierarchical navigation with `self.pushController(withName:, context:)`